# Pull all duplicate keys from list of key value pairs

Tags: c#, linq, duplicates, key

I have the following list:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, DataDetailValues>> dataResults
```

The key in the key value pair can be a duplicate - for example the list could contain:

```
Key    |    Data
1      |    ABC
2      |    DEF
3      |    GHI
1      |    JKL
```

I'd like to extract all the values from dataResults that have a key value of 1 into a second list i.e. I want:

```
 1      |    ABC
 1      |    JKL
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.where(v=vs.100).aspx):-

```
List<KeyValuePair<int,DataDetailValues>> result = data.Where(x => x.Key == 1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also work if you want to return any duplicates, even when they have a key value that isn't 1.

```
        List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> dataResults = new List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>();

        dataResults.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "one"));
        dataResults.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "two"));
        dataResults.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "one1"));
        dataResults.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, "three"));
        dataResults.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "two2"));

        var duplicates = dataResults.GroupBy(i => i.Key).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(i => i);
```